# bootstrap 4 vertical centre and positioning of div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to put some cards in a container with a parallax background effect. But while doing so, I cannot make the cards vertically centered. the row on which they are at is coming at the starting of the div. Also I want to do the container div to be relatively positioned so that the cards that are absolutely positioned will be relative to the container they're within instead of the entire page. In mobile view the cards are coming out of the div and overlapping other elements in the page. Have a look at my code below:

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid parallax">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-8">
            <div class="hovereffect">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/antoine-barres.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="200">
                <div class="overlay">
                   <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
                   <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-8">
            <div class="hovereffect">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/antoine-barres.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="200">
                <div class="overlay">
                   <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
                   <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-8">
            <div class="hovereffect">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/antoine-barres.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="200">
                <div class="overlay">
                   <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
                   <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .parallax {   
    background-image: url("/assets/images/home_services.jpg");
    min-height: 500px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .hovereffect {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:default;
    }

    .hovereffect .overlay {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .4s ease-in-out
    }

    .hovereffect img {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition:all .4s linear;
    transition:all .4s linear;
    }

    .hovereffect h2 {
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    font-size:17px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -webkit-transform:translatey(-100px);
    -ms-transform:translatey(-100px);
    transform:translatey(-100px);
    -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    padding:10px;
    }

    .hovereffect a.info {
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:transparent;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
    margin:50px 0 0;
    padding:7px 14px;
    }

    .hovereffect a.info:hover {
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #fff;
    }

    .hovereffect:hover img {
    -ms-transform:scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    transform:scale(1.2);
    }

    .hovereffect:hover .overlay {
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    }

    .hovereffect:hover h2,.hovereffect:hover a.info {
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    -ms-transform:translatey(0);
    -webkit-transform:translatey(0);
    transform:translatey(0);
    }

    .hovereffect:hover a.info {
    -webkit-transition-delay:.2s;
    transition-delay:.2s;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use flex, as the following example shows. Used most of your code, just added some background colors to make the elements visible without images.

```css
.parallax {
  background-image: url("/assets/images/home_services.jpg");
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #ff0;
  position: relative;
}

.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
  transition: all .4s linear;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-transform: translatey(-100px);
  -ms-transform: translatey(-100px);
  transform: translatey(-100px);
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hovereffect a.info {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  padding: 7px 14px;
}

.hovereffect a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2,
.hovereffect:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -ms-transform: translatey(0);
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0);
  transform: translatey(0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
  -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid parallax d-flex">
  <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/antoine-barres.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="200">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
          <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/antoine-barres.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="200">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
          <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="hovereffect">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/images/antoine-barres.jpg" alt="" width="350" height="200">
        <div class="overlay">
          <h2>Hover effect 1</h2>
          <a class="info" href="#">link here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And if you'd like to avoid setting a specific height on your `.paralax`, try using flexbox on the parent of your `.container-fluid`

Comment: Also make sure the col numbers adds up to 12 within the row. Now for col-sm you have 3 x 8, which causing a line break, and it just won't work. In my example I used col-sm-3, since it is aligned to center it has some margins left and right.

Comment: but while in small device view, the cards are still overlapping the next element which is outside the container-fluid

Comment: Indeed, but there is a hard-coded 350px width for each column's image, which makes it hard to optimize for small screens. The fix image width should be removed, and the image should be stretched to match the column width.

Comment: and how to stretch the image to match the column width???

Comment: For example `width=100% ` instead of `width=350`. But make sure you keep the aspect ratio. Remove the `height` property.

Comment: @BlackWiCKED I tried adding a separate class, as well as modifying the parallax-cell class by adding width and height to it, but it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to set a a height for a common container of these images and use flexbox to align items vertically. However, this is not super dry as a solution.

So, what you could do is take your `.container-fluid`'s container, make it a `flex` with `.d-flex` and align them with `align-items-center`.

[Here is some reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/vertical-align/) on bootstrap 4's flex utility classes.